# For loop issue with a negative values in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am new to R and I have an R  code that uses the `for` loop to calculate the y = m*i + b. The starting value is a negative and I want to use that in my calculation and store it in the first occurrence of the `Trend.Line` and so forth.

I am not getting the results that I'm expecting. If my starting is a positive number no matter what number it is, I still want to store it in the first occurrence.

For example, if `start= -5`, I would like to store this calculated value in Y <= m*i + b in `Trend.Line[1]`, the `-4` calculated value to `Trend.Line[2]`. Now if `start = 6`, I would like to store calculated value in `Trend.Line[1]`, the `7` calculated value to `Trend.Line[2]`

Thanks for looking into this.

Here is my code:

```
  Trend.Line <- numeric(0)

  start <- -5 
  end <- 12 

  m <- 345.72
  b <- 54454 

  for(i in start:end){
     y <- m*(i) + b 
    Trend.Line[i] <- y
  }  

  Trend.Line
```

Comment: Negative values in `[]` are used for omission. You can reproduce this particular example with `-5:12` or assign it with `Trend.Line <- -5:12`.

Comment: I'm sorry I have edited my R code. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Hi d.b Thank you for your time in looking into this. When I ran your code it did not give me the results.  The first occurence of the Trend.Line should be 52725.4 if I start with -5 and yours is 54799.72 which I believe it uses a positive number of 1. y = 345.72 * -5 + 54454. It should give me 52775.4. I wonder if the seq_along ignores the negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing

```
Trend.Line <- start:end
m * Trend.Line + b
```

It returns a numeric vector with everything at the index you want. It also makes use of the vectorization of functions in R. So multiplication and addition work on all elements of the vector Trend.Line.

Comment: I'm sorry I have updated my R code. See code for a resolution. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Hi MacHeath. Thank you for your time in looking into this. This is the results that I'm expecting.